# Animation code stopped working

Tags: xcode, animation, tabbar, splash-screen

I have animation code in my AppDelegate file thats making the Default.png splashscreen to fade 
out to the first controller of the app.
Since I implemented TabBar in my code, the animation stopped working.
Any idea why?

```
- (void) splashFade
{
  splashView = [[UIImageView alloc] 
                initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 480)];
  splashView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];
  [_window addSubview:splashView];
  [_window bringSubviewToFront:splashView];
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:2.0];
  [UIView 
    setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone 
    forView:_window cache:YES];
  [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self]; 
  [UIView 
    setAnimationDidStopSelector:
    @selector(startupAnimationDone:finished:context:)];
  splashView.alpha = 0.0;
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)startupAnimationDone:(NSString *)animationID 
                finished:(NSNumber *)finished 
                 context:(void *)context
{
  [splashView removeFromSuperview];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  sleep(2);

  [self splashFade];

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  // Override point for customization after application launch.

  UIViewController *viewController1 = [[RootViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RootViewController" bundle:nil];
  UIViewController *viewController2 = [[TableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableViewController" bundle:nil];

  self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
  self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
  self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

  [self.window addSubview:self.rootViewController.view];
  [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
[self performSelector:@selector(splashFade) withObject:nil afterDelay:2];
```

better than `sleep(2)`;

Comment: Alex its working but something wired happening.
The Default.png is displaying, after that - the rootview controller is shown as usuall without fadeout and just right after that the animation begins. what i mean that it repeats it's self twice. once without fading & second time with the fading.
Can u think why? i noticed that if i delete this:afterDelay:2 the fadeout not working at all.

Comment: I did it :). need to put it in the buttom of didFinish (thanks Kjuly) this is the right way: sleep(1.8);
    
    [self performSelector:@selector(splashFade) withObject:nil];
    
    return YES;